# Merge-Replication: New column doesn't get replicated down by update command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication

I do this frequently but all clients have this fault:

**I added a new column to a table using a SQL statement**, which causes the column to be created and added to every publication that uses this table.

**Now I create values by using an update statement**.

**The column and the values are properly replicated** from server to server, but all clients based on Express only get the field but **no value.**

The log shows successfully updates of the **right number of table rows**, but it needs little time as if nothing is transferred.

**Changes that were made on the client are successfully replicated up to the server.**

Also I **deleted some unnecessary columns and then recreated the new column**, same here.

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 with merge replication, no filters. The column limit is 246 columns, but I use 112 at the moment. Reproducing the error fails on a copy of the database, recreating the abonnements (subscriptions) is not an option for me.

Edit: Checked the last created columns and found this additional info. I added 4 columns earlier that are not in use yet. 2 of them have the same issue.

Comment: `but all clients based on Express only get the field but no value.` Are there any conflicts that merge agent is showing ?

Comment: Nope, it also happens to new abonnements.

Comment: @Daniel Based on what your saying I think it requires to generate a snapshot and to reinitialize subscriptions..

Comment: @Pathum Reinitializing with new snapshot results in clients having the missing data from snapshot, but are not synchronizing changes as described.

Comment: Hi, can you please post the code you used to add the column(s) and update the values?

Comment: Simple "alter table add column" and "update" commands. The publication uses replicate db scheme option.